# MySQL how to convert multiple value from a reference table

Tags: mysql

**MYSQL - Given that i have 2 tables**

***tbl_tag***

```
+------+-------------------+
|  ID  |       VALUE       |
+------+-------------------+
| 8001 | Software Engineer |  
| 8002 | C# Developer      |  
| 8003 | PHP Developer     |  
+------+-------------------+
```

***detailed employee***

```
   
id      name      current_pos   current_id  prev_pos         prev_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001    John      C# Developer       8002   Software Engineer      8001    
1002    Drew      PHP Developer      8003   Software Engineer      8001    
1003    Marco     C# Developer       8002   PHP Developer          8003    
1004    Ashley    Software Engineer  8001   C# Developer           8002   
1005    Tomas     C# Developer       8002   Software Engineer      8001    
1006    Alison    PHP Developer      8003   C# Developer           8002
```

i want to insert the id of the given position to the ***employee*** table given that the position id can be found from ***tbl_tag*** table. I only want the value's id to be inserted into the data.

This should be the output

***employee***

```
    
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
|  id  |  name  | current_pos_id | prev_pos_id |  
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| 1001 | John   |          8002  |       8001  |  
| 1002 | Drew   |          8003  |       8001  |  
| 1003 | Marco  |          8002  |       8003  | 
| 1004 | Ashley |          8001  |       8002  |  
| 1005 | Tomas  |          8002  |       8001  |  
| 1006 | Alison |          8003  |       8002  |  
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

*this is my code so far.... i don't know how to make it multiple*

```
INSERT INTO employee (name, current_pos_id ,prev_pos_id)
SELECT 'Michael', tag_id as curr_pos, tag_id as prev_pos
FROM tbl_tag 
WHERE value = 'PHP Developer'
```

i want to insert michael with current position is PHP Developer and prev position is C# Developer. Thank you!

```
                                        
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
|  id  |  name  | current_pos_id | prev_pos_id |  
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
| 1007 | Michael|          8003  |       8002  |  
+------+--------+----------------+-------------+
```

Sorry for my long post, I'm a beginner in **MYSQL**, and sorry for my english it's not my native language. Thank you!

Comment: Is `detailed employee` an actual table, or just some information you happen to show us in the form of a table?

Comment: just some information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select form two table  .. so you could use eg: a cross join each table related  to job you need

```
INSERT INTO employee (name, current_pos_id ,prev_pos_id)
SELECT 'Michael', a.tag_id as curr_pos, b.tag_id as prev_pos
FROM tbl_tag a 
CROSS JOIN bl_tag a 
WHERE a.value = 'PHP Developer' 
AND b.value = 'C# Developer'
```